# Is a linear search algorithm the same as a brute force algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am working on some leetcode tests and I am confused on the difference between a 'linear search' and 'brute force' algorithm, are they essentially the same thing?

For example, I have the below code that finds the subarray with the largest sum, and returns its sum.

I'm not sure if I have used a 'linear search' or 'brute force' algorithm in this instance?

```
const maxSubArray = function(nums) {
 let max = 0

 for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  let totalSum = 0
  for (j = i; j < nums.length; j++) {
    totalSum += nums[j]
    max = Math.max(totalSum, max)
  }
 }

 return max
};

maxSubArray([-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4]); // 6
```

Comment: A 'brute force' algorithm is a simple algorithm with non-optimal time complexity. Your code is an example of 'brute force' because it computes the sum of every possible subarray, resulting in O(n^2). The problem can be solved in O(n) time using [Kadane's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane's_algorithm).

Comment: You can read about [linear search here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search#Application). Linear search *can be* brute force. For example, if the array is sorted, then a binary search could be used instead.

Comment: @user3386109 so this is where I am confused, you mention that a linear search can be a brute force, but what are the differences between the two.  i.e. is it a case that if there are only 5 elements to be checked against then is it linear search but if there are 500 elements to be checked against, then it is brute force?

Comment: **'brute force' is an adjective** that indicates the quality of an algorithm. It's applied to a variety of different algorithms that solve all sorts of problems. **'linear search' is a noun** that describes an algorithm used to solve a one very specific and very simple task. You can use the adjective 'brute force' to modify the noun 'linear search' in situations where a different (but more complicated) search provides better time complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "brute force" is typically applied to algorithms that test every candidate solution in order to give an answer. That can lead to algorithms with varying complexities.

Linear search is a brute-force O(n) algorithm that tests every possible element in an array looking for a match. The [Maximum Subarray Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) admits an O(n^2) brute-force algorithm (like yours, testing all subarrays) while a linear algorithm is known. A brute-force algorithm to the [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) runs in O(n!) time, testing all possible permutations of nodes.

In fact, for many NP-hard problems, we don't know any algorithms with better complexity than a brute-force enumeration of the search space.

Answer (score 2):

'Brute Force' is typically used to refer to the application of an algorithm that's significantly less efficient than an optimal algorithm for a given problem. While there are all kinds of in-between complexities, the major ones are:

- constant
- log
- linear
- n log n
- quadratic
- cubic
- polynomial
- exponential
- factorial

So the confusion around whether linear search in a list is 'brute force' or not comes about because for sorted lists there's a log-time solution (binary search), and for unsorted lists the best you can do is linear.